# The astable 555 timer broke down after a few hours. Why?

Tags: high-voltage, 555, geiger-muller-tube

Eager to put my new Geiger-Müller tube to the test, I embarked on the journey of crafting a custom circuit for the purpose.

This is my circuit:

[image]

Getting straight to the point, my circuit successfully operated after a few tests. The unfortunate twist is that the astable multivibrator NE555 timer unexpectedly stopped functioning after a few uses, leaving me puzzled about the cause. I'm reaching out for your assistance to understand why it broke suddenly and seek guidance on how to fix the issue.

Comment: No decoupling capacitor. No butee resistor with the pot at discharge pin ... No limiting resistor wired serial with 100 mH ...

Comment: Are you sure it is the 555 and not the npn?

Comment: Where should I put the decoupling capacitor? and what is a butee resistor? @Antonio51

Comment: The NPN transistor works. @StainlessSteelRat

Comment: @Doobalo when the pot is to zero (high position), you must limit the current from the power supply ... so insert a resistor to do that (1 kOhm would do).

Comment: Is the MOSFET rated for the expected high voltage? The comment about a resistor on the discharge pins is relevant since you could potentially short the supply to the discharge pin at a full adjustment. The output MOSFET is not current limited, if the 555 output stops or runs slow a continuous high on the MOSFET gate will try to pull a large or continuous current through the inductor and itself. Try coupling the MOSFET gate with a capacitor to prevent it from getting stuck in the on state. Decoupling capacitors are a good idea (from power pins to GND) especially with pulse circuitry.

Comment: I noted also that you don't have a "regulation" system. The output voltage "could" then be "anything".

Comment: Assuming it is just the astable NE555 as the defective part, my guess is that it may have accumulated damages from spikes above Vcc (18V max) and/or when being reverse polarized (V+ below GND), even if that happens for very short duration. This could be prone to happen after battery is used, increasing its internal resistance. To minimize/avoid that, I would suggest using a decoupling capacitor in parallel to battery, and protecting with a resistor (as 47R) the supply of NE555 with a Zener//capacitor (12Vz//100uF). I could detail it later a bit more, as an appropriate answer, if necessary.

Comment: @Antonio51 do I put the 1k ohm in series with the POT? Pot from trigger to discharge then 1k from discharge to Vin? and of course the pot needs the middle pin to be attached to one of its ends right?

Comment: @Nedd yes the mosfet can handle high voltage. Its rated at 600V. About the decoupling capacitor, do I put it form Gate to GND or like in audio in series with the 100ohm resistor? 

PS: what capacitance 100n 1u 10u?

Comment: For basic decoupling place small caps close to each chip's + pin to GND, (100nf is good). A high value cap on the inductor + pin to GND can also help, (100uf or more). To capacitively couple the MOSFET place a cap in series with the gate followed by a high value resistor to gnd (maybe 100nf & 1k or so). There is still the potential to burn out the first 555 with over current & over voltage, (see other comments). In addition, note your high voltage cap has no discharge path at shut off. A few high meg-ohm resistors to GND can be used to allow it to discharge safely and prevent a shock hazard.

Comment: @Nedd Are you suggesting connecting a capacitor from the output of the 555 timer to the gate of the MOSFET, and then placing a resistor from the capacitor to ground? Wont that create a negative voltage?

Comment: A 555 is really not a good way to make a boost converter. Try using a flyback based on a dedicated controller like an LT1871 or something.

Comment: @Antonio51 What does "butee resistor" mean? I've never heard the term before.

Comment: @Doobalo, No, the cap blocks a DC state.  The resistor would simply allow the cap to charge and discharge,

Answer (score 1):

For best explaining the 1 kOhm position ... I made this circuit.
You can see what happens when the cursor of the pot is "high".
As showed, the current through R13 is very "high", like 0.8 A ...
This is bad for the 555.

[image]

You should add also a "decoupling" R-C (in green) at supply of MOSFET ...

[image]

Note also that your circuit lacks a "regulation" system for the voltage output.

Comment: I truly appreciate your assistance! Planning to test this tomorrow since it's quite late in my timezone. I might return if I encounter any hiccups and or do something stupid :)

Comment: Tested it today and it seems more happy :) Thank you. Lets see if it lasts.